# How to find the max of the count of records based on a categorical variable

Tags: mongodb

I want to find the start station with the max number of rides but Im not sure how since start station name is not a numerical field.  A single document looks like

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("572bb8222b288919b68abf86"), "tripduration" : 1087, "start station id" : 280, "start station name" : "E 10 St & 5 Ave", "end station id" : 527, "end station name" : "E 33 St & 2 Ave", "bikeid" : 20945, "usertype" : "Subscriber", "birth year" : 1990, "gender" : 2, "start station location" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ -73.99510132, 40.73331967 ] }, "end station location" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ -73.976056, 40.744023 ] }, "start time" : ISODate("2016-01-01T00:16:08Z"), "stop time" : ISODate("2016-01-01T00:34:15Z") }
```

Ive tried the aggregate function with $max and .count()

```
db.trips.aggregate({$group: {$max: "start station name"}}).count()
```

This gives an error:

> "The field '$max' must be an accumulator object"

Comment: How does a street name relate to number of rides?

Comment: I think you mean "count of the same **distinct** starting point"? Yes? i.e `.aggregate([{ "$count": "$start station name" }])`

Comment: I might also suggest reading [SQL to Aggregation Mapping Chart](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/) in the core documentation. If you have at least *some* familiarity with SQL and you are only just starting to use MongoDB, then this can be a good reference point to introduce of some common statements would translate, and then really act as a *springboard* to look further into the documentation examples for the operators demonstrated there.

Comment: Also, sorry but forgot to add the `$sort` and `$limit` to the pipeline example above for the "max" part. Would be in full, `.aggregate([{ "$count":  "$start station name" },{ "$sort": { "start station name": -1 } }, { "$limit": 1 }])`. That's also covered in the other existing answers and the [`$count`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/count/) documentation, which basically aliases a `$group` as shown in other examples with an added `$project` stage to rename the field.

Comment: @chris p bacon.  Each ride has a distinct starting point.  So I want the starting point that is the most frequent starting point.  ok? yes, thank you Neil

Comment: @NeilLunn I used that but said "the count field cannot be a $-prefixed path"

Comment: My bad. `$count` just expects the name of the property. So just `{ "$count": "start station name" }` for that part. As you should see in other examples, using `$group` would indeed want the "dollar prefix" as it expects an *expression*. i.e `{ "$group": { "_id": "$start station name", "count": { "$sum": 1 } } }`